# How can I read a double-semicolon-separated .csv with quoted values using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I analyse huge financial data-sets that often give me trouble because of corrupt data fields. Luckily, in the near future I get the opportunity to change the way data is delivered to me. The data will get delivered as a double-semicolon-separated txt-file with the fields in double quotation marks, i.e. "A";;"B";;"C"

In using pandas' read_csv to convert this file to a pandas df, however, pandas doesn't seem to recognize the double quotation marks, only the double-semicolon separator. Because the output looks like: "A" "B" "C", instead of A B C

I've tried passing quotechar='"' as a parameter and quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, but that doesn't change anything.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv


def create_df(loc):
    df = pd.read_csv(loc, sep=';;', dtype=object, encoding="ISO-8859-1", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, header=None)
    return df


directory = 'C:\\PycharmProjects\\Test\\'
file = directory + 'test;;qq;;.txt'

df = create_df(file)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, 'test')
writer.save()
```

Comment: Can you create a dummy dataset of a few lines, upload it(preferably on your github) and link it here, I have some massive confusions about how exactly your dataset looks and thus don't want to create a solution for a problem with the odds that it might not be the problem, as of what I understand now, I would read the entire CSV as a string, use some regex magic and transform it to a proper csv, but I think I can give you something more conclusive if you can create a dummy dataset.

Comment: you can try 
`df.apply(lambda s:s.str.replace('"', ""))`
where df is your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug when `pandas` has to use the `python` engine due to the separator not being a single character, if you pass a single character separator then it imports and parses those columns correctly but you end up with additional columns:

```
In[80]:
import csv
t='''"A";;"B";;"C"'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
df
Out[80]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, Unnamed: 1, B, Unnamed: 3, C]
Index: []
```

then you can drop the extra columns by filtering:

```
In[81]:
df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.contains('Unnamed:')]
df
Out[81]: 

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C]
Index: []
```

Comment: Thanks EdChum. So that means I either have to use single semicolon separated data in quotes, or double-semicolon separated data without quotation marks.

Comment: Yes that's correct, it looks like the quoting param is ignored when using the python engine. Depending on your data size it maybe quicker to load it using the 'c' engine anyway by passing a single character for the separator. Of you could pre-process the file by replacing the double semi-colon with a comma.