# How can I read a double-semicolon-separated .txt in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, file

I have this problem but in r:

[How can I read a double-semicolon-separated .csv with quoted values using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513358/how-can-i-read-a-double-semicolon-separated-csv-with-quoted-values-using-pandas)

The solution there is to drop the additional columns generated. I'd like to know if there's a way to read the file separated by ;; without generating those addiotional columns.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read it in normally using `read.csv2` (or whichever variant you prefer, including `read.table`, `read.delim`, `readr::read_csv2`, `data.table::fread`, etc), and then remove the even-numbered columns.

```r
dat <- read.csv2(text = "a;;b;;c;;d\n1;;2;;3;;4")
dat
#   a  X b X.1 c X.2 d
# 1 1 NA 2  NA 3  NA 4

dat[,-seq(2, ncol(dat), by = 2)]
#   a b c d
# 1 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

It is usually recommended to properly clean your data before attempting to parse it, instead of cleaning it WHILE parsing, or worse, AFTER. Either use Notepad++ to Replace all `;;` occurences or R itself, but do not delete the original files (also a rule of thumb - never delete sources of data).

```
my.text <- readLines('d:/tmp/readdelim-r.csv')
cleaned <- gsub(';;', ';', my.text)
writeLines(cleaned, 'd:/tmp/cleaned.csv')
my.cleaned <- read.delim('d:/tmp/cleaned.csv', header=FALSE, sep=';')
```